# how to write to android hardware buffer in vulkan？

Tags: android, buffer, external, hardware, vulkan

In OpenGL, the texture of which memory is imported by android hardware buffer can be used as sample image and color attachments. However, when I try to use texture of which memory is imported from android hardware buffer, it seems than it can sampled from the texture successfully. But when writing to the external memory, it does not work as expected.So how to write to android hardware buffer directly in vulkan?

I consulted the documentation specification of vulkan. In the following link,
[https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#memory-external-handle-types](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)  in chapter of 11.2.17, i found the specification said "Vulkan can import Android hardware buffers that have external formats, but since the image contents are in an undiscoverable and possibly proprietary representation, images with external formats must only be used as sampled images, must only be sampled with a sampler that has Y′CBCR conversion enabled, and must have optimal tiling".Is that means that Android hardware buffers that have external formats cannot be used as color attactments to be write?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you please update here if you were able to solve this issue?

Comment: I find that it may be impossible to write to AHB buffer directly. But maybe u can export meomory allocating in vulkan to AHB. Perhaps, exporting the vulkan memory to opengl memory, then sampling from the opengl texture and writing to AHB.